# Migrate files with document property promotion

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, metadata

I'm trying to migrate files from a SPS 2010 with document property promotion
to a modern SharePoint online site.

Doc property promotion/demotion should be migrate as is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you intending to use Microsoft Search when you have migrated your site?

Comment: That would be the long term plan, indeed

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the SharePoint Migration Tool to migrate, for more information please refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool